# Trying to use Jquery hover to change font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Im trying to use the Jquery hover function to change the font size of some tabs. I think im having trouble targeting the tabs.

This is the HTML im trying to target:

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
    <div class="tab">
        <li class="tab-title">
            <a href="#panel2-1">ABOUT ME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="tab-title">
            <a href="#panel2-2">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li> 
    </div>
</ul>
```

I just tried wrapping both tabs in a div tag and assigned the div tag a called "tab"

This is my Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('font-size','60px')
    });
});
```

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use CSS? It's way faster than trying to do it with jQuery.

Comment: Yep, CSS is cool. Also I usualy use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead. But use CSS

Comment: @NoahHuppert `mouseexit` ... you mean `mouseleave`.

Comment: It works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/gr078khd/

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. Im trying to improve my skills with jquery...

Comment: Yeah it seems to be working fine on jsfiddle, but it doesnt work in my chrome browser

Comment: Are you loading your js file properly? Does it work when you create an `alert`.  Also, just playing around maybe this is more in line with what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/gr078khd/1/?

Comment: Works fine for me also, tested on Chrome & Firefox. Make sure and include the jQuery library ??

Comment: Is this how you include the jQuery library? :<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Just figured it out! I had assigned it a font-size in my css page and i guess it was it overriding my .hover. Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DIV` element is not allowed inside `UL` so that's your first mistake, it should be:

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
  <!-- no party for DIV elements here -->
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-1">ABOUT ME</a></li>
  <li class="tab-title"><a href="#panel2-2">PORTFOLIO</a></li> 
</ul>
```

`.hover()` will never return our text to the default state, cause actually the `.hover()` method listens for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so on mouseleave you're again setting it to `60px`

CSS on the other hand will do it:

```
.tabs li:hover a{ /* Or use>> .tabs a:hover */
   font-size: 60px;
}
```

If you really are just interested in jQuery just for fun than:

```
$('.tabs li').hover(function( e ) { // or simply '.tab-title'
   $("a", this).css('font-size', e.type=="mouseenter"? 60 : "inherit"); // or 56
});
```

also using jQuery you don't need to set `px` cause *px* are used by default unless another unit is set.